# filter and tag the text stream in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, text, stream

The problem is to tag the text if text contains one of the keywords that is defined in tag's keywords. Also the tags can have same keywords so if the text is "the weather in istanbul is sticky." and there are two tags with the keywords

```
tag["first"]:["istanbul"],
tag["second"]:["istanbul","weather"]
```

this text should be tagged with these two tags(first and second).

My current solution is to merge all keywords with the tags they are connected. They become like this:

```
istanbul: ["first","second"],
weather: ["second"]
```

After this I use basic indexOf() to figure out if the text has the keyword or not in a forEach loop.

**First:** indexOf() has some problems with Turkish characters so I don't want to use it. Any suggestions is appreciated.

**Second:** Is there any library that I can use in this situation?

Tell me if I'm doing wrong.

I can share the code as well if it is needed.

Comment: Lunr.js? https://github.com/olivernn/lunr.js/